# Access to Amazon S3 public files forbidden on iPhone only

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, bucket

I'm having this weird issue where files hosted on a bucket that is public and accessible work the way it should on every platform except on iPhone, where I get 403 forbidden on files.
This happens on both Safari and Chrome.

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

Comment: Object keys are case-sensitive. Are you sure the request being made is _identical_ to other platforms? One way to test is to send yourself an email with the URL. Then, click the URL on your computer and your phone and see if the results are different. This will ensure the URL is identical in both tests. Also, check whether the request is being sent as HTTP or HTTPS.

Comment: I've always tested from the same link that was sent on a group chat, so that's not it :/. And yes it is a https connection

Comment: Can you share a sample URL?

Comment: https://calm-3d-files.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/Calm3D/index.html - on iOS the screen just stays black as it fails to load essential javascript files

Comment: It worked perfectly fine for me. I used an iPhone 11, with both Safari and Chrome. Very nice how the picture moves around when I move the phone! However, clicking "I'm Ready" doesn't do anything -- is that what you were saying was a problem? I then selected "Use desktop site" in Chrome and the button worked correctly. So, it might be a coding problem rather than an S3 problem.